# Как создать EXT4 раздел с U-Boot?

Tags: linux, boot, arm, разметка-диска

У меня имеется SD карта с U-Boot. Записывал так:

```
 ~ # dd if=uboot-with-spl.bin of=/dev/sdd bs=1024 seek=8
```

Я хочу прямо рядом с U-boot создать ext4 раздел, чтобы из него загружать zImage через bootz. (да, я пошёл по сложному пути, а именно - что-то вроде LFS, только для ARM плат). Сам zImage есть, UART могу себе обеспечить, создать ramdisk с нуля мне труда никакого не составит, даже init свой напишу. Вопрос: как мне из Linux и чем создать раздел на карте, чтобы в дальнейшем именно туда поместить, ядро, ramdisk, а в дальнейшем остальную систему?

UPD: пробовал метод отсюда, U-Boot не загружался: https://linux-sunxi.org/Bootable_SD_card

UPD2:

0andriy, вы говорите про offset для ext4. Ничего подобного там и близко нету:

[image: lфото1]

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы информации не даёте достаточно. Каким образом ваш U-Boot вообще может грузиться? Для поддержки SD контроллера на плате должна быть фирмварь, что это конкретно? Где ссылки на документацию? Читана ли она?

Comment: у меня грузится U-boot, если записать его на sd карту через DD, как я и делал. Я писал именно SPL-образ (uboot-with-spl.bin)

Comment: Дальше, даже если вы и положите рядом раздел с ext4 (это всё делается через временный файл и `mount -o loop ...`), как ваш U-Boot к нему доступ получит? У него есть поддержка offset для раздела ext4?

Comment: Не, так разговор у нас с вами не клеится. Читайте ещё раз мои комментарии, там есть над чем подумать, и как дополнить вопрос, чтобы его минусовать не стали.

Comment: мой defconfig: https://github.com/Dima-diep/uBoot-orangepilite/blob/master/configs/orangepi_lite_new_defconfig

Comment: < каким образом ваш U-Boot вообще может грузиться? > Всмысле? На таких платах всегда есть поддержка SD карт, даже если они идут со своим emmc внутренним

Comment: 0andriy, вынес ответ вам в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B=1
K=$[1024*B]
M=$[1024*K]

MicroSD=/dev/sdd
MNT=/mnt
UBOOT=uboot-with-spl.bin # путь к
SECTOR_SIZE=$[512*B]
START_BOOT_RECORD=$[8*K]
PARTITION_START=$[1*M]

dd if=/dev/zero of=$MicroSD bs=$[PARTITION_START] count=1 conv=fsync oflag=direct status=progress
echo -e "label:dos\nstart=$[PARTITION_START/SECTOR_SIZE]" | sfdisk $MicroSD
dd if="$UBOOT" of=$MicroSD bs=$[START_BOOT_RECORD] seek=1 conv=fsync oflag=direct status=progress

yes | mkfs.ext4 -O '^metadata_csum,^64bit' -m1 ${MicroSD}1
mount           ${MicroSD}1 "$MNT"
...
umount          "$MNT"
```

кода-то развлекался с одноплатоником чем-то подобным, это часть изысканий по подготовке диска под дальнейшую установку, возможно подойдёт под вашу задачу

Comment: Он читать не умеет, так что это не поможет ;)

Comment: @0andriy,  но у него есть официальная клавиатура SO ;)